# Put text and form next to photo using bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

This is my HTML:

```
<div class="row trolibelanja">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <img src="http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-WGiyrP7xGOk/VQlHwjgporI/AAAAAAAABHI/zLGXTH0-H2w/s1600/Mie%2BAyam%2B(4).jpg" class="detailfoto">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <p class="detailnama">Mie Ayam Bakso</p>
        <p class="detailtoko">Toko Bu Lastri</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <p class="detailharga">Rp. 30.000</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btnjumlah" type="button">-</button>
            </span>
            <input type="text" class="form-control jumlah" value="1">
            <span class="input-group-btn">
                <button class="btnjumlah" type="button">+</button>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-1">
    </div>
</div>
```

This is my css:

```
body{
    background-color: #661f61 !important;
    font-family: 'Saira Extra Condensed', sans-serif !important;
}

.container-fluid.keranjang {
    background-color: #e9e9e9;
    flex: 1;
}

.container.keranjang {

}

.row.trolibelanja {
        background-color: #e1e1e1;
    position: relative;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 23px;
}

.row.trolibelanja:after{
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(135deg, #6e1c64 25%, #e27f31 25%) !important;
    position: absolute;
    content: " ";
    width: 100%;
    height: 15px;
    bottom: 0;
}

.detailfoto {
    width: 100%;
    height: 110px;
    border: 6px solid white;
}

.detailnama{
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.detailtoko{
    line-height: 20px;
    margin: -17px 0px;
}

.detailharga{
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
}

.input-group .jumlah {
    width: 50%;
    text-align: center;
}

.input-group .btnjumlah {
        background-color: #e27f31;
    color: white;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 0px 10px;
    height: 100%;

}
```

I am trying to put text and form next to photo using bootstrap, as in photo below:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HI91M.png)

**My code result:**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lPnOS.png)

Please let me know what am I missing? I tried each combination of display that i know, but they wouldn't work. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Arrange your columns properly. And you will be good. put image in one column (`col-md-3` in this case) and rest of the content in another (`col-md-9`), then put all rest of the content in a new row. I would suggest that you have a better understanding of the rows and columns from bootstrap website.

https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_system.asp

```html
    <div class="row trolibelanja">
                        <div class="col-md-3">
                            <img src="http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-WGiyrP7xGOk/VQlHwjgporI/AAAAAAAABHI/zLGXTH0-H2w/s1600/Mie%2BAyam%2B(4).jpg" class="detailfoto">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-9">
                          <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <p class="detailnama">Mie Ayam Bakso</p>
                                <p class="detailtoko">Toko Bu Lastri</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-2">
                                <p class="detailharga">Rp. 30.000</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-2">
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <span class="input-group-btn">
                                    <button class="btnjumlah" type="button">-</button>
                                    </span>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control jumlah" value="1">
                                    <span class="input-group-btn">
                                        <button class="btnjumlah" type="button">+</button>
                                    </span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `flex-wrap: nowrap;` to your `.row.trolibelanja` like this:

```
.row.trolibelanja {
    background-color: #e1e1e1;
    position: relative;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 23px;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
}
```

I made codepen example with your code: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wPZoXX

Comment: @Setya You should choose answer that helped you so others can now this one is solved.

Comment: From the existing answers, can not succeed 100% as I described. All the answers are really helpful and I use all the combinations of answers.

Answer (score 0):

i ran your code on bootsnipp and found everything is placed side by side to each other, except for the fact that you did not add img-responsive to the image class. and that the below code is distorting your design.

```
    .row.trolibelanja:after{
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(135deg, #6e1c64 25%, #e27f31 25%) !important;
    position: absolute;
    content: " ";
    width: 100%;
    height: 15px;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

dont you what you intent designing with that, but i think you need to run a check that css code .

when i added your css to it, it distort the whole code.

1. first review your CSS is well written , targeting the right class.
2. second add img-responsive to the img class and i think you are good
   to go.